# javascript setInterval() and Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

OK, I have read several questions here with the same title but still couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm working on a basic javascript count down timer and I'm stuck on updating the value of the `a` variable.

```
a = 100;
var i = setInterval( function(){ timer( a ); }, 1000 );

function timer( a ){
    console.log( a );
    if( a < 1 ){     
        console.log( 'Reaching Stop' ); 
            clearInterval( i );
            return;         
    } 
    a -= 1;
}
```

As I'm decrementing the value of `a` by -1, `console.log( a )` should be 1 less every time i.e

```
100 99 98 ......
```

But `console.log( a )` is always giving `100`

newbie to javascript here please be gentle.
thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should not pass `a` in parameter of `timer` function to access the global variable `a`. When `a` is passed to timer function the value of global variable is used but in timer the parameter variable is local to timer function and changing the value of it wont change the value of global variable. It means you have two variables in your code having name `a` one is global and other is local to timer function and you are changing value of local variable of timer.

```
a = 100;
var i = setInterval( timer, 1000 );

function timer() {
    console.log( a );
    if ( a < 1 ) {
        console.log( 'Reaching Stop' ); 
        clearInterval( i );
        return;         
    } 
    a -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the variable as a parameter to a function, you create a closure, which creates new scope for the variable.

Since the variable is global, you don't need to pass it in:

http://jsfiddle.net/FBVTT/

```
var a = 100;
var i = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    console.log(a);
    if (a < 1) {
        console.log('Reaching Stop');
        clearInterval(i);
        return;
    }
    a -= 1;
}
```

Here's an [MDN page on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: Yup,its working and im more confused now ...lol ,if i pass it as a variable ,does it become a different variable then ?

Comment: Yes, it has a different scope. It's not like reference types in c#, for example.