# How do I solve this issue of the pictures not changing?

Tags: javascript

Hey so i developed this code to allow me to change the images based on a timer. As the countdown hits certain milestones the picture changes. But unfortunately I cannot get this to work as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Change the lights automatically</h1>

<img id="myimg" src="1.png" width ="100" height="300">

<script>

var list = [
    "1.jpg",
    "2.jpg",
    "3.jpg",
    "4.jpg"
];

var count = 0;
var time=20;

var timing=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
(
    var newImage = document.getElementById('myimg');
    time = time-1

    if (time <= 1) time = 20;
    if (time >15 && time < 21) count = 0;
    if (time >10 && time <16) count = 1;
    if (time >6 && time <15) count = 2;
    if (time >1 && time <5) count = 3;
    if (time = 0) count = 0;

    var newImage = document.getElementById('myimg');
    newImage.src = list[count];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have do is , the code should have a timer that runs every one second, when the timer is between a certain amount the value of count should change accordingly. Afterwards as i have set the new image to be changed each time the value of count changes , the image displayed should change however this is not the case as it doesn't change. Any experts out there can identify what is wrong with it so i can fix it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ofcourse each of the image directories contents doesnt really matter ^^

Comment: Your original src is `.png`, but `list` contains `.jpg`. Are you sure you got the names right?

Comment: This seems overly complex. Why not run it every 5 seconds, and just increment `count` each time.

Comment: You have a typo. The `(` at the beginning of the function should be `{`. Is that in the real code or a copying error? If it's in the real code, didn't you see a syntax error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your time is always 19 or time-1 on the timer function
you might consider taking a look this 
[javascript setInterval() and Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123440/javascript-setinterval-and-variable-scope)

Hope this helps

check the following code snippet

```js
var list = [
    "1.jpg",
    "2.jpg",
    "3.jpg",
    "4.jpg"
];

var count = 0;
var time=20;

var timing=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
function timer()
{
var newImage = document.getElementById('myimg');
  
  time=time-1;
    if (time <= 1) time = 20;
    else if (time >15 && time < 21) count = 0;
    else if (time >10 && time <16) count = 1;
    else if (time >6 && time <15) count = 2;
    else if (time >1 && time <7){ count = 3;}
    else if (time == 0) count = 0;
  else 
  {
  clearInterval(timing);
  return;
  }
    var newImage = document.getElementById('myimg');
  console.log(newImage.src);
    newImage.src = list[count];
  }
```

```html
<img id="myimg" src="1.png" width ="100" height="300">
```

Comment: Oh thanks , this worked but I am sort of confused at to the whole "console.log" thing , anywhere i can look to find out more about this?

Comment: And one last thing , why have you got "time = time-0;" is it neccessary?

Comment: it is not needed too ...I was trying to change it to number,it was for debugging purposee too (its already a number)

Comment: Ah i see , so if i just remove the whole line , console.log(time) it should still work? One more thing , the program seems to be stuck at picture 3 for some reason when i use your code. Any ideas why? o.O

Comment: There are few issues with your if conditions ...modified the code snippet check once

Answer (score 2):

The final if condition assigns time to 0.

```
if (time = 0) count = 0;
```

time will always be 0 so

```
newImage.src = list[count];
```

always displays the same image. Remove the final if condition and amend the first one.

```
if ((time >15 && time < 21) || (time == 0)) count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the curly brace here...

function timer()
(

... it should be

function timer()
{

Comment: The curly brace is on the next line.

Comment: Except it's a parenthesis. That's the typo.

Comment: We should wait to find out if that's in the real code or a copying error here.

Comment: Sorry copying error =/ fairly new to using the website and i should've double checked before posting it .