# SetInterval not fetching the latest prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component to which we are passing  `isAlive` as a prop which has an initial value as `false` from the parent component, I have an indefinite `setInterval` which `console.log` whether the person is alive or not. As and when the prop is getting updated the latest value is not getting reflected in the set interval at run time and it's retaining the original value always which is `false`.

```
const printUserStatus = ({isAlive}) =>{

    setInterval(() => {

        if(isAlive === false){
             console.log("the user is Dead");
        }
        else if(isAlive === true){
             console.log("the user is Alive");
        } 
    },1000);
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to [mahdi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62413867/5928272) approach, have solved it by the following way -

```
const printUserStatus = ({isAlive}) =>{

    const isAliveRef = useRef(isAlive);
    isAliveRef.current = isAlive;

    setInterval(() => {

        if(isAliveRef.current === false){
             console.log("the user is Dead");
        }
        else if(isAliveRef.current === true){
             console.log("the user is Alive");
        } 
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you intentionally want to read the latest state from some
>   asynchronous callback, you could keep it in a ref, mutate it, and read
>   from it.

Check out [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

Basically the value you see is the value of the `isAlive` when the function was first called.

Answer (score 1):

Check this 6 years old answer about how  `setInterval` work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123476/13647574

use something like `useRef()` to avoid this