# Variable scope in setInterval

Tags: javascript, scope

I am strugling with variable scopes in simple timer. I know how scopes work, but still can't figure out this problem.

I found this: [javascript setInterval() and Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123440/javascript-setinterval-and-variable-scope) witch is almost my problem, but my variable is not global.

```
function set_timer(duration) {
    setInterval(function () { do_count(duration); }, 1000);
}
function do_count(duration){ console.log(duration--); };
set_timer(100);
```

It should be 100 99 .... , but it is 100 100. I tried to set or remove duration without success. As I understand it, duration is global for everything in set_timer, but nope.

```
function set_timer(duration) {
    setInterval(function () { do_count(); }, 1000);
}
function do_count(){ console.log(duration--); };
set_timer(100);
```

is "duration is not defined".

Why isn't it working?

Comment: You are not decrementing the `duration` value inside `set_timer()` function so every time `do_count()` function is called, value of duration is `100`. Do this --> `do_count(duration--)` inside `set_timer()` function

Comment: See you're doing more PHP. What's the difference between `$arg` and `&$arg` as a function argument? JS has no `&$arg`.